# Why doesn't this work for Rudin Exercise 8 Chapter 3 series proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Okay so Here is the problem:

> If $\sum{a_n}$ converges and $b_n$ is bounded and monotonic, prove that $\sum{a_nb_n}$ converges.

So I can follow the long epsilon based proof and I'm good with all that, but why can't I just do this?:

If $b_n$ is bounded by $M$
$$\sum{\lvert a_nb_n\rvert} =\sum{\lvert a_n\rvert \lvert b_n\rvert} \le \sum{\lvert M\rvert \lvert a_n \rvert} = \rvert M \lvert \sum{\lvert a_n \rvert}$$

Now that I'm writing this, is this wrong because $\sum{\lvert a_n \rvert}$ doesn't necessarily converge?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Yes, it is wrong because $\sum |a_n|$ need not converge.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof would indeed work if $\sum_n|a_n|$ is finite. In this case, we even have the absolute convergence: $\sum_n |a_nb_n|\lt \infty$.

But the argument does not work if the convergence is not absolute, for example if  $a_n=(-1)^n/n$. Somehow, we have to make appear the partial sums of $a_n$ and exploit the monotonicity of $(b_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$, and an Abel's transform does the job.